How to remove CSS from @tanstack/react-router Link component?
I'm using the React MUI List component and the tanstack router Link component
<List>
    <Link to="/customers/$customerID" params={{ customerID: 123 }}>
        <ListItemButton>
            <ListItemText primary="Customer 123" />
        </ListItemButton>
    </Link>
</List>

The code works as expected but the Link component overwrites the CSS of the MUI ListItemText component.
Without the Link component the fake data is rendered like this

and with the Link component the fake data is rendered like this

Adding style={{ textDecoration: "none", textDecorationColor: "currentColor" }} to the Link component didn't fix it.
I created a small playground for reproduction. Do you know how to solve this?

Seems like somewhere you have a CSS code/MUI configuration setting default values for Link element. By default it's inherit for text-decoration.
I created a sandbox and by default Link element is removing default text decoration and color. Look for global CSS rules for a elements or MUI settings.
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/elated-margulis-67njfz?workspaceId=ws_PE2qM11kenbugPmP3PExem

I had a look at your sandbox and I'm really sorry but how did you fix it... ? I can't find the code for it

I don't have any custom CSS, not even a .css file in my code

I added a playground for reproduction to my question

you seem to giving css at wrong place just give css to </Link/> tag instead of </ListItemText/>
style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}

Restructure your code like this
<List>
  <Link
    to="/"
    style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }} // Inline style for Link
  >
    <ListItemButton>
      <ListItemText primary="Text" />
      <ListItemText primary="Text" />
    </ListItemButton>
  </Link>
</List>

